# ORMLite how to make '<=' with two columns in same table?

Tags: android, where-clause, ormlite

I want to make one query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table where column_one <= column_two;
```

With QueryBuilder I can to make `where().le(column_one, Object obj)`, but I want some like `where().le(column_one, column_two)`;

Actually, I want the following query:

> SELECT * FROM table_one INNER JOIN table_two ON
>   table_one.column_foreign_id = table_two.id WHERE table_two.column_one
>   <= table_two.column_two.

What is the best way?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using [rawQuery](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#SEC26) instead?

As the docs say:

> The built-in methods available in the Dao interface and the
>   QueryBuilder classes don't provide the ability to handle all types of
>   queries.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can do it. 
Code:

```
QueryBuilder<Account, String> queryBuilder = accountDao.queryBuilder();

queryBuilder.where().le(Account.COLUMN_ONE_NAME,
    new ColumnArg(Account.COLUMN_TWO_NAME));

List<Account> results = queryBuilder.query();
```

More information here: [see 3.7 Using Column Arguments](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_3.html#Column-Arguments)